# How to create buffer for video streaming

Tags: android, ffmpeg, streaming, buffer

I am developing a Android video player that can play RTSP Stream. I use ffmpeg in jni part to get and decode RTSP Stream. For now, the player can play and then pause video stream. The next step is to create a buffer for the player so that when user pauses video, the player can still load video stream in the next several seconds.

Is there any good documentation on how to create a buffer for video streaming in proper way?

My plan is to create a array of packets. When the array is full, the player calls

```
 av_read_pause();
```

to stop buffering. When the array has spaces, the player will call

```
 av_read_play();
```

to continue buffering. There is a read_thread for getting packets from the buffer and the decode the packets. The read_thread will stop (resume), when user pauses (resume) video.

Can this plan work?